# Python 3 default python

Tags: python

I want to make python 3 as default in raspberry pi 3b and install scikit-learn and scikit-plot for the python 3 version. What are exact steps to be followed. Appreciate your input.
Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by `make python3 as default`?

Comment: @yamboy1, yes. Can it be done by adding 'alias python=python3' in the ~/.bashrc file and then typing alias python=python3. But then how to revert to python2.

Comment: @yamboy1, sorry for not mentioning it clearly. Making python 3 default means whenvever I open a py file, it should open in python 3 IDLE. And when I install any new package it should be for the python version 3. In my case, currently basic packages such as scipy and numpy are installed for python 2, but when I run a code in python 3 IDLE, I get error....Import Error: No module named 'scipy'

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/320996/how-to-make-python-program-command-execute-python-3 covers the details you need to beaware of as for python2 after aliasing python3 create aa second alias for python2

Comment: What operating system do you use?

Comment: For the raspberry pi 3b, the default OS raspbian is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run linux command `ls -l python*` within the directory, you will see that `python` is just a symlink to python2.7, if you know linux commands well enough, you can easily make a change to link `python -> python3`.

One more thing you need to aware is that in order to install packages for python3, you need to run `pip3`. This is probably the reason that you run into the case where "No module name 'script'" error. Again, run `ls -l pip*` to find out more.

You can also run `pip3 list` to check what packages are installed for python3.

Comment: For many reasons, it is not a good idea to point `/usr/bin/python` to `python3`. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43062608/how-to-update-alternatives-to-python-3-without-breaking-apt

Comment: @Bex, I won't recommend messing with the default installation either (which is the link that you referred to is doing). However, to put a symbolic link so that typing `python` to launch `python3` instead of the default `python2` is a different story, and do no harm for the fundamental system installation.

Comment: Instead of changing the default system-wide you could change it just for your pi-user. Do this: `sudo apt install python3; mkdir ~/bin; ln -s /usr/bin/python3 ~/bin/python`. Log your user out and log back in. Do this: `which python`, This should return `/home/pi/bin/python`. Now everthing under this user will use the symlink which points to python3. Delete `~/bin/python`, log out and back in to revert this change.