# .bashrc runs python2 instead of python3

Tags: python

I am trying to get a python code to run on boot on the raspberry pi. I added the following line to the .bashrc file at the end of the file:

```
sudo python3 /home/pi/code.py
```

The pi uses python2 to run the code instead of python3. Why is this happening and how can I make it run python3?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 3 default python](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/69591/python-3-default-python)

Comment: No, I don't want to make python3 my default python version. Thanks though.

Comment: What is the added line to .bashrc meant to do?  Call the script at shell start?  How do you know it is not working?

Comment: Please show the first line of code.py

Comment: `.bashrc` will not be executed at boot, so whatever is starting your script at boot time using Python2 it is not the line you're looking at.

Comment: @bls I see what you're getting at, but Python3 will run a script starting with `#!/usb/bin/python2` just fine.

Answer (score 1):

`.bashrc` is **NOT** intended to run scripts.

It is run each time a non-login interactive shell is started and is used to configure the shell.
`~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells`.

There are many ways of running scripts, depending on what you are trying to do. 
See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/47537/8697 for an example.

(There are other problems with the script, but as you shouldn't use it for this purpose, not relevant.)